# markov chain probabilities from transition matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm given a chain with state space {1,2,3} and transition matrix: 
P=
        \begin{pmatrix}
    .1 & .4 & .5 \\
    0 & .3 & .7 \\
    .8 & .2 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}

the question is asking me for the probability that the first 5 states visited are: 1,1,3,2,3
I don't know how to start this because every other problem gives an initial condition and this one doesnt.  I can calculate the probability of the string if I know I'm starting at 1, which would be .1*.5*.2*.7, but don't know what to do for the start.

Comment: I would assume that you are given a starting point, otherwise, it is an open question.

Answer (score 0):

You must be given either a starting state or a probability distribution on starting states in order to complete this problem. Perhaps it was intended that you take 1 to be the starting state, but that should be clarified by your professor. You are not failing to understand something here; the problem is indeed underspecified.

It sounds like once you have a starting state, or starting distribution, you know what to do here. You describe what to do if the starting state is given, but just to add to that: if a starting probability distribution is given instead of a starting state, then you would simply multiply the figure you arrived at by the probability of starting at 1.

Comment: there is no more information given in the question.  maybe I'm supposed to calculate the stationary distribution and take the corresponding value as the probability of starting with that state?

Comment: @DustyPencil Why would you do that? Either take 1 as the starting state, compute *conditional* probabilities for all possible starting states, or, as suggested, ask your professor to clarify the problem.